# ESP32 ModBus master half duplex read coil input registers

Tags: modbus, arduino-esp32

I'm trying to read a MODBUS sensor via an ESP32.

I'm using the following library: https://github.com/emelianov/modbus-esp8266

I have the following code:

```cpp
#include <ModbusRTU.h>
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial modBusSerial;

ModbusRTU modbus;

#define startReg 100
#define endReg 123
uint16_t res[endReg - startReg + 1];

// Callback to monitor errors in the modbus
bool cb(Modbus::ResultCode event, uint16_t transactionId, void* data) {
    if (event != Modbus::EX_SUCCESS) {
        Serial.print("Request result: 0x");
        Serial.print(event, HEX);
    }
    return true;
}

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(115200); // Default serial port (Hardware serial)

    modBusSerial.begin(9600, SWSERIAL_8E1, MB_RX, MB_TX); // modbus configuration SWSERIAL_8E1 = 8 bits data, even parity and 1 stop-bit
    modbus.begin(&modBusSerial);
    modbus.master();
    Serial.println("starting modbus...");

    while (true) {
        Serial.println(modBusSerial.read());

        res[endReg - startReg] = 0;  // string terminator to allow to use res as char*

        if (!modbus.slave()) {
            modbus.readIreg(16, startReg, res, endReg - startReg, cb);
        }
        modbus.task();
        Serial.print("result: ");
        Serial.println((char*) res);
        delay(1000); // every second
    }
}
```

Response I get;

[image]

When I do the exact same in `QModMaster`, I do get the correct output. Anyone any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

These are the settings I use;

[image: settings]

I am aware of the "wrong" address in my code. I have 2 identical sensors but one is connected to my computer while the other one is connected to my ESP32.

Thanks in advance!